# Where can I find statistics for Facebook and YouTube total views worldwide like those of Wikipedia?

Tags: research, social-media, internet

I am working on a research program about social media traffic and my mission is to find official usage data for major platforms like YouTube, Facebook, Twitter, Wikipedia etc.

**Wikipedia provides official Worldwide stats per year https://stats.wikimedia.org/#/all-projects**

Does anyone know where I can find similar **official source about Facebook, YouTube, and Twitter statistics?**

Please note that both Youtube and Facebook provide some metrics worldwide about **Monthly Active Users (MAUs)** and **Daily Active Users (DAUs)** but my goal is to find yearly records about total page/video/tweet views like [Wikipedia's](https://stats.wikimedia.org/#/all-projects)